# Updates and inserts by improving ON/GROUP By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-merge

Here is the sample of the Source and target table. I only have one unique id called "Premise_ID". I would like to update the target table based on Premise ID. When i am running below mentioned SQL query then I am getting an error mentioned below. I am having multiple rows with the same Premise_ID but with different column attributes.if the first Premise_ID matches then update all the column attributes. if the second Premise_ID is same as previous one then just add another row with all the column attributes. Is there any way to overcome this error?

Source Table

[image]

Target Table

[image]

SQL Query:

```
USE GIS_NewJersey
GO
WITH Source AS (
    SELECT Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType
    FROM sde.SAP_Load_test
),
Target AS (
    SELECT Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType
    FROM sde.PREMISE_test
)
MERGE Target t
USING Source s
  ON t.Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    Division = s.Division,
    InstallationType = s.InstallationType
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType)
    VALUES (s.Premise_ID, s.Division, s.InstallationType)
;
```

ERROR:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3 columns in `MERGE SEARCH CONDITIONS` and use `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` to `INSERT` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` to `DELETE`

```
USE GIS_NewJersey
GO
WITH Source AS (
    SELECT Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType
    FROM sde.SAP_Load_test
),
Target AS (
    SELECT Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType
    FROM sde.PREMISE_test
)
MERGE Target t
USING Source s
  ON t.Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID
  AND t.Division = s.Division
  AND t.InstallationType = s.InstallationType
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType)
    VALUES (s.Premise_ID, s.Division, s.InstallationType)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
  DELETE
;
```

Comment: Hello Mohamad,  When i am running your query on real data then I am getting this error message "Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 110
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OBJECTID', table 'GIS_NewJersey.sde.PREMISE'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated"  There is a OBJECTID field in sde.Premise_test which should get created automatically. Here is the full query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=647b554c7aad214a7fcbb473f2226a16

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b66334ba9b1ec173a1ec01e4791dd00 . I have created a db fiddle for you to take a look at it.

Comment: There are 2 object ID already present then after running the query the object id needs to start with 3 and above. How to approach this?